# Detect an invalid paypal email using MassPay Paypal API

Tags: api, paypal

I'm using [MassPay Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/) to make payments. 
I was able to test it and is working pretty well using sandbox accounts. 
**The problem is I couldn't find a way to identify if the email that is going to receive money is a valid paypal email.** 
I tested it using a fake email and money was taken from the payer sandbox account even though the email (the one that should receive the money)  doesn't have a paypal account associated, and the API response was as if it was a successful request. 
I found this [method to get the verification status of an account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/#verifying-the-status-of-a-paypal-account), but there is no much info in the documentation or any other info that helps me understand if this is what I'm looking for or how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an API operation called GetVerifiedStatus API Operation under PayPal adaptive accounts. Refer the below:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/gs_AdaptiveAccounts/

Sample API request:
API end point: https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage = en_US&emailAddress = email@test.com&firstName = Firstname&lastName = Lastname&matchCriteria = NAME